# Как сделать одновременную раздачу файла нескольким подключениям

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, flask, веб-сервер

Сервер выглядит вот так:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)


@app.route('/files/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)


app.run()
```

Для загрузки использую такой код, который запускал на нескольких процессах:

```
def sizeof_fmt(num):
    for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB']:
        if num < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f%s" % (num, x)
        num /= 1024.0
    return "%3.1f%s" % (num, 'TB')


def progress(count, block_size, total_size):
    percent = count * block_size * 100.0 / total_size
    print("Download: %s/%s(%3.1f%%)" % (sizeof_fmt(count * block_size), sizeof_fmt(total_size), percent) + ' ' * 20,
          end='\r')

urlretrieve('http://127.0.0.1:5000/files/bigfile', "file", reporthook=progress)
```

И пока один не скачает файл или не прервется его работа, следующий скрипт ждет.
Опыта написания серверов у меня нет, поэтому прошу подсказки как это сделать. Flask не обязательный, просто хочу такой сервер сделать.

Если с одним сервером такое сделать невозможно, то как такую задачу решить? Например, сайты, которые показывают фильмы делают такую же задачу. Не будет же там такого, чтобы пока один не просмотрит фильм, все остальные over9000 клиентов ждут этого знаменательного события :)

**UPD.**

Сервер использовать хочу для поддержки api, которое на get запрос возвращает json, и в json будет путь к файлам на сервере. Файлы могут быть большими (до нескольких гигов).

**UPD2**

Думаю попробовать запустить nginx как прокси, он будет по url определять запросы к файлам и отдавать их, а остальные запрос отправлять текущему серверу на flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался...

Проблема была в том, что `flask` по умолчанию поддерживает одно соединение.

И чтобы дать ему возможность работать с несколькими соединениями, нужно при запуске указать параметры `threaded` или `processes`, пример:

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

Ссылка на ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823968/5909792

---

**UPD 16/03/2021.**

**Сейчас это уже не актуально, т.к. в `flask` режим `threaded` по умолчанию включен.**